# insert a time-stamp value in my db by php

Tags: php, sql, timestamp

I'm using oracle express and in my application i would insert a time-stamp value in my table:

```
$marca = date('y-m-d H:i:s');

    $query = "  INSERT INTO SA_VERSIONE
                    ( ID_ACCETTAZIONE, MARCA_TEMPORALE, TESTO, FIRMA, MEDICO)
                    VALUES
                    ('$id', '$marca', '$testo', '$firma', '$medico')
        ";

        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);

        oci_execute($stid);
```

but when execute it return:

Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-01843: mese non valido in ...
and say that the month is not valid

Comment: Seems like date format on your Oracle server is different than 'y-m-d H:i:s'

Comment: when i add a time-stamp directly from the db i wrote 
ex. 2010-04-07 12:34:43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_timestamp` should work for you.

If `MARCA` isn't already a TIMESTAMP field, i suggest you make it one.

```
  $query = "  INSERT INTO SA_VERSIONE
                    ( ID_ACCETTAZIONE, MARCA_TEMPORALE, TESTO, FIRMA, MEDICO)
                    VALUES
                    ('$id', current_timestamp, '$testo', '$firma', '$medico')
        ";
```

Comment: return: Call to undefined function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$marca = date('dd-mmm-yyyy H:i:s');
```

Comment: Uh.. have you? "1515-060606-10101010 16:48:05"

Comment: @MSpreij: i don't undestand XD

Comment: @Erick: see http://php.net/date , the format input takes a single character per value, so 'Y' becomes '2010'. 'yyyy' becomes 10101010.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
INSERT INTO SA_VERSIONE
                    ( ID_ACCETTAZIONE, MARCA_TEMPORALE, TESTO, FIRMA, MEDICO)
                    VALUES
                    ('$id', '$marca', '$testo', '$firma', to_date($marca, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi:ss));

Look into the to_date format options.  They must match what you are inserting to what Oracle expects.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SYSDATE` instead of generating time by PHP

```
<?php
$query = "  INSERT INTO SA_VERSIONE
                ( ID_ACCETTAZIONE, MARCA_TEMPORALE, TESTO, FIRMA, MEDICO)
                VALUES
                ('$id', SYSDATE, '$testo', '$firma', '$medico')
    ";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);

oci_execute($stid);
?>
```

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Oracle expects a slightly different format, '10-JUN-15' - try date('y-M-d H:i:s'). If the time is not valid in there, check the url for more ideas :-)

http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html